# how to configure google clasp in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, clasp

I am working on automating clasp push via Jenkins.
So, far I have achieved setting .clasprc.json as a Jenkins environment variable.
The clasp is installed in "C:\Users\superuser\AppData\Roaming\npm" and is accessible on cmd.
However, Jenkins is not recognizing it.

```
cd c:/test
@echo %CLASPRC_CRED% 1>./.clasprc.json
clasp push (THE STEP THAT IS FAILING)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by changing the logon service account for Jenkins.